# Correlation matrix heatmap range on a target value

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, correlation, feature-extraction

I am trying to figure out how I can do a correlation matrix heatmap with SNS with heatmap values from a target column. I am trying to identify if combination of 2 features have an effect on the target_value.

I know I can do following but this is correlation between features but not correlation of 2 features on `target_value`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.heatmap(dataframe.corr());
```

I have following CSV

```
feature_1,  feature_2,  feature_3,  feature_4,  target_value
4,          8,          9,          8,          0.1
9,          7,          2,          0,          0.2
4,          4,          1,          4,          0.6
9,          7,          8,          4,          0.7
0,          9,          0,          7,          0.9
```

I could encode them as followed based on a threshold to define presence (1) or not present (0) of that feature.

```
feature_1,  feature_2,  feature_3,  feature_4,  target_value
0,          1,          1,          1,          0.1
1,          1,          0,          0,          0.2
0,          0,          0,          0,          0.6
1,          1,          1,          0,          0.7
0,          1,          0,          1,          0.9
```

I would like to know correlation of feature_1:4 on the target value. I would also like to know if/how I could filter the correlation features shown on axis? For this I guess I can filter the dataframe based on `target_value` However, I am not sure how I can show/hide features on the axis

e.g.
`feature_1` and `feature_2` on X axis /
`feature_3` and `feature_4` on Y axis
for target value >= 0.5

e.g.
`feature_1` and `feature_2` on X axis /
`feature_3` and `feature_4` on Y axis
for target value < 0.5

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' `corrwith()` helps to find the correlation between one column and the others. As the result is a series and seaborn expects a dataframe, the series  needs to be converted to one.

To find the correlation between `feature_1`/`feature_2` and `feature_3`/`feature_4` for a subset of the target values:

- take the desired subset of the dataframe
- calculate the correlation
- take some rows/columns from the correlation matrix

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'feature_1': [4, 9, 4, 9, 0],
                   'feature_2': [8, 7, 4, 7, 9],
                   'feature_3': [9, 2, 1, 8, 0],
                   'feature_4': [8, 0, 4, 4, 7],
                   'target_value': [0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.7, 0.9]})

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(16, 5))

corr_with_target = df.drop(columns='target_value').corrwith(df['target_value'])
sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(corr_with_target), ax=ax1)
ax1.tick_params(rotation=0)
ax1.set_xticks([])
ax1.set_title('Correlation with target value')

corr_for_large_target = df[df['target_value'] >= 0.5].corr().loc[['feature_1', 'feature_2'], ['feature_3', 'feature_4']]
sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(corr_for_large_target), ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Correlation for large target')

corr_for_small_target = df[df['target_value'] <= 0.5].corr().loc[['feature_1', 'feature_2'], ['feature_3', 'feature_4']]
sns.heatmap(pd.DataFrame(corr_for_small_target), ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('Correlation for small target')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: correlation heatmap with one target column]

Comment: Just for clarification, it's not the correlation between `feature_1/feature_2` and `feature_3/feature_4` It's the combined effect of these features on the target value. I am not sure if I am using the correct terminology. What's represented in the axis is correct but the values for the heatmap should be based on `target_value`.? I hope it makes sense. I am trying to say that `feature_3` + `feature_1` has an effect on `target_value`. `feature_3` + `feature_1` doesn't have an effect on `target_value`.

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s12864-017-4353-7/figures/1 - trying to reproduce something like this

Comment: These figures seem to be created via `sns.clustermap`.   I'm not sure how you combine two features.  Just summing them could be replaced by some weighted linear combination, or even some more complicated formula.

Comment: I already have binary encoded individual feature values based on a threshold. 1-present, 0-not present. Does that mean I need some additional set of columns? to represent the combined effect of features? If I were to say presence of both features = 11 => 1, not present = 01, 10 or 00 => 0 how can I do the last 2 graphs in the answer? I've also added encoded CSV to the question.